# AppleScript - Copying Folder Content shows error - Download & UnZip Works

Tags: download, copy, applescript, unzip

**UPDATE01:** The cleaned Up code - Zip download was removed and current issue is that the 'Copy' command gets executed before 'unzip' is completed; resulting in a copy of an empty folder over to the destination folder. when running as an .app but when running as a script in AppleScriptEditor.. it runs fine :/

```
property DownloadsFolder : path to downloads folder
property appSupport : path to application support from user domain
property ZIPName : "ResourcesOffline.zip" -- downloaded ZIP file
property AppName : "MyApp" -- name of App in Application Support
property ExtractedFolderName : "MyContent" -- name for folder in Downloads where ZIP is saved
property ExtractedFolderPath : ((DownloadsFolder as text) & ExtractedFolderName & ":")
property DataFolder : ":UserBottle:FFApp:D_C:PData:LP:App:Data"

-- inform user of process --
display dialog "
IMPORTANT:
Before running this App, please be sure you have downloaded the 'ResourcesOffline.zip', and it is in your 'Downloads' Folder.
Press [OK] when you are ready to start.
" buttons {"Ok"}

-- Set up DSResources folders in Downloads and User's Bottle --
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (POSIX path of ExtractedFolderPath) & space & quoted form of POSIX path of {(appSupport as text) & AppName & (DataFolder as text) & ":DSResources"}

display dialog "Check! Directories in Downloads and Data" buttons {"Ok"}

-- Extract to the folder created in Downloads --
try
    do shell script "unzip -u " & quoted form of POSIX path of ((DownloadsFolder as text) & ZIPName) & " -d " & quoted form of POSIX path of ExtractedFolderPath
on error
    display dialog "
    Process failed.
    Could not find 'ResourcesOffline.zip' in 'Downloads' folder.
    Please be sure that the file exists in the specified location.
    " buttons {"Quit"} with icon 0
    if button returned of the result is "Quit" then error number -128
end try

display dialog "Check! UnZipped in MyContent" buttons {"Ok"}

-- Copy items to the folder created in Application Support --
tell application "Finder"
    set SourceFolder to folder (ExtractedFolderPath as text)
    set DestinationFolder to folder ((appSupport as text) & AppName & (DataFolder as text))
    duplicate (entire contents of first folder of SourceFolder) to DestinationFolder with replacing
    display dialog "
    All content was copied successfully. Thank you!
    " buttons {"Ok"}
end tell

display dialog "Check! All done - About to Delete TEMP Extracted files" buttons {"Ok"}

do shell script "rm -rf " & quoted form of POSIX path of ExtractedFolderPath

quit
```

==========================================================================

I am new to scripting, in general. Carry a basic understanding, but not much of a programmer.

I am trying to write an AppleScript script to do the following:

1. Download 'XXX.ZIP' from 'http://MyLink.com/XXX.zip'
2. Download in 'Downloads' folder and overwrite any existing file if it already exists
3. Show a progress bar of the download (<- I know a progress bar is tough, so this is a nice to have
4. Once downloaded, unpack the ZIP in same 'Downloads' location

- Once Unzipped: I will have this (this is what is in the ZIP already):

  - One Main Folder [001]

    - One SubFolder in MainFolder [001A]

      - One File in MainFolder 001B.txt

**Up till here all works fine; however from this point onwards I am struggling**

5. Copy 'All Contents' of MainFolder (not the main folder itself; just the subfolder and text file in it) from 'Downloads' folder to 'Library/Application Support/MyApp/Resources' and Replace any existing files
6. Once copied, display popup dialogue that 'process is completed' - [OK]

**Notes:**

- I am using ~/Folder locations because this script is for anyone to use, so I can't hard code the full path i.e: MacHD/Users/USERNAME/Downloads .. etc

**PS** - I am new to coding; so a lot of things in this code may seem 'senseless'; but I am trying so please bare with me. I have gone through a lot of forums to derive what I have but Gods of coding aren't happy with me… I am having issues trying to make all this work; this is the script I have till now:

```applescript
set newFolderPath to quoted form of (expandPath("~/Downloads/MYCONTENT"))
set cmdStr to "if [[ ! -d " & newFolderPath & " ]]; then
    mkdir -m 755 " & newFolderPath & "; fi"
do shell script cmdStr
on expandPath(pPathStr)
    local fullPath
    set fullPath to pPathStr
    if fullPath = "~" then
        set fullPath to (POSIX path of (path to home folder))
    else if fullPath starts with "~/" then
        set fullPath to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & text 3 thru -1 of fullPath
    end if
    return fullPath
end expandPath
-- Download --  
tell application "Finder"
    do shell script "curl -L -o ~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/SOME_RESOURCES.ZIP 'https://MyWebsite.com/Stuff/DownloadableContent/SOME_RESOURCES.ZIP' > ~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/status 2>&1 &"
    set fileSize to 0
    set curTransferred to 0
    set curProgress to 0
    repeat until curProgress = "100"
        try
            set lastLine to paragraph -1 of (do shell script "cat ~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/status")
            set curProgress to word 1 of lastLine
            set fileSize to word 2 of lastLine
            set curTransferred to word 4 of lastLine
            tell me
                display dialog "Downloading; Please wait, this will take a while.
                Status: " & curTransferred & " of " & fileSize & " (" & curProgress & "%)" buttons {"Refresh", "cancel"} giving up after 5
                if the button returned of the result is "cancel" then return
            end tell
        on error
            display dialog "Download failed. To restart the download, please press the 'Retry' button" buttons {"Quit", "Retry"} with icon 0
        end try
    end repeat
    set theDialogText to "Download is complete. Press [OK] to continue"
    display dialog theDialogText
    -- Extract --
    do shell script "unzip -u  ~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/SOME_RESOURCES.ZIP -d ~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/"
    do shell script "/bin/sleep 10"
    -- ** FROM HERE ONWARDS I AM GETTING AN ERROR **
    -- Copy --
    set DownloadFolder to "~/Downloads/MYCONTENT/RESOURCES/"
    set DestinationFolder to "~/Library/Application Support/MYAPPLICATION/RESOURCES/"
    copy every file of folder (DownloadFolder's entire contents) to folder DestinationFolder
    set theDialogText to "All content has been copied. Thank you!"
    display dialog theDialogText
end tell
```

Comment: Do you just want a straight solution to your problem, or would you like code revisions as well, to make your script cleaner?

Comment: @Ted Wrigley; new to coding and enjoying it a bit... So any help is appreciated. Straight solution/Revision/Cleanup with a bit of explanation to what is being done and why... so that I can learn from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outline and script example are a bit different, so I went with the outline:

- Create folders in the user's **Downloads** and **Application Support** folders as needed
- Download a zip file to the folder created in **Downloads** and extract it to that folder - the zip file contains a main folder containing a sub folder (or folders) containing files
- Copy the entire contents of the main folder to the **Resources** folder in the folder created in **Application Support** for the application

There are a few ways to do a progress bar or download status using some AppleScriptObjC, but for better control those should probably be done from an application.

The main problems with your script are that the **Finder** does not understand POSIX paths, and you missed creating the folder structure in **Application Support**.  There are standard commands to get paths to the various system folders, so string manipulations aren't needed to get the script to work on other machines.  In the following script, I keep track of the regular HFS paths, just coercing them to POSIX for the shell scripts, and added properties for the various names so they are in one spot.

```
property downLoads : path to downloads folder
property appSupport : path to application support from user domain
property webPage : "HTTPS://MYWEBSITE.COM/STUFF/DOWNLOADABLECONTENT/"
property webResource : "SOME_RESOURCES.ZIP" -- name for the downloaded file
property myApp : "MYAPPLICATION" -- name for folder in Application Support (bundle identifier would be better)
property baseName : "MYCONTENT" -- name for folder in Downloads
property basePath : ((downLoads as text) & baseName & ":")

-- Set up folders in Downloads and Application Support as needed --
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (POSIX path of basePath) & space & quoted form of POSIX path of ((appSupport as text) & myApp & ":Resources")

-- Download and progress - more error handling is needed --  
do shell script "curl -L " & quoted form of (webPage & webResource) & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of (basePath & webResource) & " > " & quoted form of POSIX path of (basePath & "status") & " 2>&1 &"
set fileSize to 0
set curTransferred to 0

set curProgress to 0
repeat until curProgress = "100"
   try
      set lastLine to paragraph -1 of (do shell script "cat " & quoted form of POSIX path of (basePath & "status"))
      set curProgress to word 1 of lastLine
      set fileSize to word 2 of lastLine
      set curTransferred to word 4 of lastLine
      tell me
         display dialog "Downloading; Please wait, this will take a while.
                Status: " & curTransferred & " of " & fileSize & " (" & curProgress & "%)" buttons {"Refresh", "Cancel"} giving up after 1
         if the button returned of the result is "Cancel" then return
      end tell
   on error
      display dialog "Download failed. To restart the download, please press the 'Retry' button" buttons {"Quit", "Retry"} with icon 0
      if button returned of the result is "Quit" then error number -128
   end try
end repeat
display dialog "Download is complete. Press [OK] to continue"

-- Extract to the folder created in Downloads --
do shell script "unzip -u " & quoted form of POSIX path of (basePath & webResource) & " -d " & quoted form of POSIX path of basePath -- Main Folder > Sub Folder > text file

-- Copy items to the folder created in Application Support --
tell application "Finder"
   set downLoadFolder to folder basePath
   set DestinationFolder to folder ((appSupport as text) & myApp & ":Resources")
   duplicate (entire contents of first folder of downLoadFolder) to DestinationFolder with replacing -- contents of "Main Folder" -- 'duplicate' is the command to use for files
   display dialog "All content has been copied. Thank you!"
end tell
```

Change the placeholder items in the properties as needed - Note that the shell scripts and web file names are case sensitive.

Comment: thank you for the guidance and cleanup, the way code is written in your example makes it really easy to understand what exactly is the code doing. I just wanted to know about this line:   property appSupport : path to application support from user domain   ... is this the line that tells the code to run on any system regardless of the path to downloads/AppSupport folder? I had read we were to use $HOME in the path to tell the code to look for that path in the UsersHome folder.

Comment: `$HOME` is one of those useful constants in shell scripting.  In AppleScript, there is also the `path to` command from the **Standard Additions** scripting addition that provides paths to various macOS system locations.  `path to Downloads folder` is the current user's **Downloads** folder, and `path to application support from user domain` is the user's **Applications Support** folder (there are _system_, _local_, and _user_ domains for that one).  When mixing **Finder** and shell script commands, I find it easier to convert from AppleScript, so I tend to use those commands.

Comment: Ah Ok; gotcha... seems AppleScripting is fairly close to human lingo; follows a basic logic structure as well. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain and resolve my issue - I will try your suggested edits later tonight and update you on what I find. Again, your efforts and help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @red_menace; so I have worked with what you suggested & did quiet alot of changes; and thanks to the way you had layed out the base; everything I have done to the code has worked. However; one small thing; in your suggestion; you stated this line:
-- Extract to the folder created in Downloads --
The extraction of the ZIP is taking a while and the code jumps on to the next 'duplicate' command; meaning while the unZip is happening; the copy begins; so not everything gets copied... is there a way I can tell the code to wait for the unZip to finish? ideally a process check; if not a timer?

Comment: Unless it is set to run in the background (as you did with the `curl` command), `do shell script` will not return until the command is done.  You could add a short delay after the unzip to make sure everything is settled down.

Comment: It is not a 'curl' command; it is being run as 'do shell script "unzip -u "'; so I am not sure why when I have the code run in the script editor with debugging (basically a popup dialogue box after every main action); the whole code executes fine; but the minute I run it as an .app; the copy happens too early so the copied files are not there at destination. Let me post my Frankenstein code and perhaps you can point out what/where am i going wrong.

Comment: Hi @red_menace; I couldnt find out how to send the new code in comments section; so I have updated my original post with the updated code. Hope its easy for you to find.

Comment: Ok; so a bit more info on this; the code does what it is supposed to on a *hit/miss*... I can see the code works fine on the FIRST RUN on a CLEAN STATE... and when I reRun it right after that (dirty state); it starts making 'SubFolders' at destination when it does the Copy... meaning if this code is being run on a system that already has folders in the destination of same name, instead of writing/replacing those folders, it creates 'SubFolders' within them... so... any Help? :/